# Support only landscape mode on iPad with Size classes & Autolayout

Tags: autolayout, uikit, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout, size-classes

Is there anyway to support only Landscape mode on iPad and disallow rotations to Portrait mode with size classes enabled? All views are laid out in storyboard with auto-layout enabled.

Answer (score -1):

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .phone:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    case .pad:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
    case .unspecified:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    default:
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }

}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```

1) implement these two method in your viewcontroller.

2) Then go to storyborad and select your viewcontroller

3) Then from below select option ipad

4) change orientation to landscape

5) then click vary on trait button

6) Now your view controller is in landscape mode, so give constraints of view whatever you like .it will change for ipad only because you have selected ipad.

7) after that click done varying. and its over

Comment: Can you describe it step by step where to start with? Where do I click 'iPad', in Storyboard?

Comment: Implementing autorotation methods has no effect on iPad with autolayout & size classes!

Comment: you are doing wrong implementation. It is working fine for me.

Comment: This implemntation allows iphone to only portrait mode and ipad to only landscape mode, which is your requirement right??

Comment: It doesn't. iPad orientation still changes on autorotation.

Comment: iPhone anyways is in Landscape mode given the option selected in plist. Problem is iPad.

Comment: Have you debug it? because in my case it is working. it is swift 3 and xcode 8

Comment: Ok I solved it. Found that supported interface orientations (ipad) still contained portrait mode options in info.plist. Simply removed it and now it works! No need for above code.